# django in virtualenv with pydev

Tags: django, pydev, virtualenv

mac ox 8.2, eclipse juno, python 2.7, django 1.4.1, pydev 2.7.1.2012100913

I'm relative new with python/django and I'm trying to get it to work with pydev in a virtualenvironment. I set up the virtualenvironment installed django and successfully created and started a django project. After that I decided that I want to use my favorite editor eclipse.

I created a new pydev/django project, configured and selected a new interpreter (from virtualenv) and used that, I also included the virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django in the interpreter libraries. However after going the next dialog, I got an error message "Django not found"

I went over the documentation but I haven't found any solution yet.

I was also wondering whether the workenvironment (or the actual code) needs to live in a subdirectory of the virtualenv directory) And whether the virtualenv must be activated (I suppose so), tried all these options but no luck yet.

Comment: can you import django from shell within the virtualenv?

Comment: `import django`, in Python shell is working from virtualenv, as well as `./manage.py shell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you don't need the django installation (i.e., virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django) in your interpreter libraries.  Having the site-packages in there (i.e., virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages) should suffice for your interpreter to find any django.* package.

Answer (score 2):

putting this in your interpreter libraries:

```
virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
```

wiil not work, because there is no `virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/django` (yes, twice), this translates to the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=<...virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django:$PYTHONPATH
python -c 'import django'
```

which fails with `ImportError` message. you need to give the parent directory.

```
virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

which translates to the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=<...virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
python -c 'import django'
```

.